# Install Entrust SSL certificate in Node express application

Tags: node.js, ssl, express

I'm not sure how to pass in the given certificates to start the https server. Entrust provided the following files:
1. Root certificate. (.txt)
2. Chain root cert file. (.txt)
3. Chain certificate. (.txt)
4. Server certificate. (.crt)

My express app currently takes:

```
exports.key1 = {
    key:'./server/config/keys/server.key', // ?
    cert:'./server/config/keys/server.crt', // ?
    ca:'./server/config/keys/ca.csr' //given to entrust to generate their cert
};
```

I'm not sure how to modify the key to match the new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've concatenated your certificates, instructions for this are provided by your issuer, you'll need to read them from the file system and provide them to [`http.createServer()`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener) to create a SSL server object. From the documentation:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/agent-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/agent-cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

Usually, you'll wrap the options block in a flag to check whether you are in production or development. For production, you'll read the certificates from a secure, pre-defined path, whilst for development you can generate these and provide them in a root project folder `fixtures/`, which you can also distribute with the project repository if it's more convenient. Use the following to create a self-issued certificate for development:

```
openssl req -batch \
    -new -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -days 365 \
        -keyout fixtures/dev.key \
        -out fixtures/dev.crt;
```

Comment: So... agent-key is my private key?  agent-cert is 1 file with items 1-4 concatenated sequentially?   I am now getting this error from chrome: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Comment: If you get a `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`, means that you haven't concatenated the files correctly together for your key. Try this tool to test that you've done everything correctly https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html

Comment: Seems to have worked. Thanks! Still getting the untrusted connection (it is a real ssl cert, not self signed). But I image it's because I'm running on localhost.

Comment: @WilliamFalcon most likely, since certificates are bound to domain names. You'd  need to have added `localhost`.